# Sonata E-commerce order bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have just installed the sonata e-commerce OrderBundle, I want to add new field in order_order table without changing anything into the vendor.

I have try it with add field into the Order entity, But it is not working.

Please help.

Thanks